# Google translate: Quota Exceeded

Tags: google-translate

I am trying to use Google Translate REST API and while requesting the following url:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=test&langpair=en|hi&key=mykey

I am getting the following response:

> Response: {"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Quota Exceeded. 
>   Please see
>   http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html",
>   "responseStatus": 403}

I am getting this message today only. I have tried using the service after one or two months. Previously it was working perfectly. Has Google stopped the Google translate free service or what?

Comment: The question should actually be: "What is the daily quota for Google Translate v1?", because the link that Google returns you explains pretty well what they're going to do with the service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You exceeded your quota. Google started to limit the number of API usages a few months back due to the large number of users using the tool excessively.

EDIT: Read the notice on the top of this page: http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html

Comment: "limit the number of API usages" Can you explain this to me in specific? What is the limit?

Comment: See my edit. Google is decreasing the limit until it hits zero on December 1, after which it will be a strictly for-pay service.

Comment: Is there any other alternative by which I can translate the text to some other language then?

Comment: Sure, you can pay for their new API - http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/pricing.html.  Pricing looks fairly reasonable, USD $20 per 1 million characters, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Google has moved to a Paid model.  We moved to the free Bing Translation API, its very similar, it seems to be better at translating and still free:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis

Example of how to use it:
http://basharkokash.com/post/2010/04/19/Bing-Translator-for-developers.aspx

Comment: In addition, you can use a non-official free google translate package here: https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the error message explains itself - there seems to be some daily quota on the use of their API, and you have exceeded it.

But yes, Google is [discontinuing](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html) the free version of their Translate API, and you will have to pay to continue to use it after December 1 2011.