# Translate not coming in google.API

Tags: vb.net

To translate english to any other language we have to write..

dim ST,ST1 as string

ST="HELLO"

ST1= Google.API.Translate.Translator.**Translate**(ST, Google.API.Translate.Language.English, Google.API.Translate.Language.Hindi)

msgbox(ST1)

but in my code window...

Google.API.Translate.Translator.**Detect** is coming. No **Translate** option is coming..

can anyone help why this is happening ??

thanks in advance
 Dev..

Comment: duplicate/merge with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932001/google-translate-quota-exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, 2011/12/1, Google will be shutting down version 1.0 of their language API. The version of the API that your library uses is 1.0.

Version 2.0 can be found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html), which costs $20 per 1 million words, with a 2 million words per day quota.

Since you probably want something free, you can use [Microsoft's Translator API](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/), where its free usage works for 2 million characters per month.